# How to prevent Azure DevOps release deletion?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-security

I am hardening our Azure DevOps, and now is time to prevent Azure DevOps release pipeline deletion.
I can realize it with changing security of each release, however it is too secure less, as new release will not inherit the rule.
So is there some global rule or some trick to prevent deletion of every release?

Comment: In addition to [Set All release Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#set-all-release-permissions) mentioned in Marcin Słowikowski's Answer, you can also pay attention to the [Release Retention Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-release-retention-policies) to avoid some old Runs accidental deleted by the Retention Policies.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify permissions on release pipeline directory level
[image: All pipelines directory]

[image: Permissions for All release pipelines]

Delete option disappeared
[image: No delete option]

Comment: It is great solution, however we have a lot of projects, also every new project need to be configured in such a way. I think, it need to be added in script.